# Emulate remote control number key presses on Android TV Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-tv, numpad

Is there a way to emulate the remote's numpad key presses (i.e. KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD) in the Android TV Emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate all key presses using adb shell command `input keyevent`. For numpad you can use the command like this: `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_NUMPAD_1`